# Failed to upload report - HTTP code 413: The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large

Tags: iis, msbuild, sonarqube, reverse-proxy, sonarqube-scan

I'm setting up a fresh installation of SonarQube Version 7.9.1 (build 27448)

It's running behind a reverse-proxy in IIS using URL Rewrite.

I can login just fine into SonarQube.

It is failing when running analysis for my .Net solution (a big one) using sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.7.1.2311-net46. It failes at the end, after compilation and analysis happened.

```
INFO: Analysis report generated in 33994ms, dir size=196 MB
INFO: Analysis report compressed in 191901ms, zip size=71 MB
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 1:46:46.636s
INFO: Final Memory: 20M/746M
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed to upload report - HTTP code 413: The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large.
ERROR:
The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
00:52:36.207  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

Googling HTTP 413 found some solutions to enable `<serverRuntime>` and set `uploadReadAheadSize` to it's max (see below).

This did not fix my problem.

[image]

Comment: Use FRT to see which module gives you 413, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 1):

I Figured it out.

It was the request filtering feature. I had to up the `Maximum allowed content length (Bytes)`

[image]

See [Large File Upload in IIS](http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-asp-net.htm)